# Copying chrome user data without closing open browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to be able to make copies of the User Data folder at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data without closing open Chrome browsers several times a day. At the moment 99% of the folder is copied except for a couple files (like Cookies) that need me to close all open browser windows for the copy to conclude? Any ideas for workarounds? Definitely can't close the browsers.

Comment: Generally, you can't. You'd need read access but the file is locked by the browser. In order to unlock the file, you'd need to close the browser.